# Python --- Write the line in r-th test file / write all train files except r-th one

Tags: python

This is the problem: Write a script that reads in a dataset, and a number k, and randomly divides the dataset into k equal folds. Then it outputs k different training and testing files. Each of the k splits will use one of the k folds as a test set, and the rest as the training set. Name the output files like: train_1.txt, train_2.txt ... train_k.txt

```
#!/bin/python
import random

k = int(input("Enter k: "))

f = open("colon-cancer.txt","r")

for i in range(k):
        i_str = str(i+1)
        file_name_train = 'train_' + i_str + '.txt'
        file_name_test = 'test_' + i_str + '.txt'

        f1 = open(file_name_train, 'w')
        f2 = open(file_name_test, 'w')
        f1.close()
        f2.close()

for line in f:
        r = random.randint(1,k)
```

I don't know how to create a for loop to write line into the r-th file, or how to write all files except r-the file.
Does anyone know how to solve it？